# How to Save to Database from ListBox?

Tags: c#, database, silverlight-4.0, listbox, datatemplate

I know how to save to my database from a datagrid's selected row, but I want to save all records from my list box to the database.  Here is the related xaml for the ListBox:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="EventDataTemplate">
       <StackPanel Name="OuterStackPanel">
          <TextBox Text="{Binding Title}" Name="TextBoxTitle"/>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding BeginDate}" Name="TextBoxBeginDate"/>
             <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding EndDate}" Name="TextBoxEndDate"/>
          </StackPanel>
          <TextBox Text="{Binding Venue}" Name="TextBoxVenue"/>
          <TextBox Text="{Binding Location}" Name="TextBoxLocation"/>
          <TextBlock Name="TextBlockID" Text="{Binding id}"/>
       </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
 </UserControl.Resources>
 <ListBox x:Name="AllEventsListBox" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EventDataTemplate}"/>
```

With my DataGrid method, I use this codebehind to save its row's related TextBoxes to the database:

```
    MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();
    client.UpdateEventCompleted += new EventHandler<UpdateEventCompletedEventArgs>(client_UpdateEventCompleted);
    singleEvent.id = int.Parse(LblID.Content.ToString());
    singleEvent.Title = TextBoxTitle.Text;
    singleEvent.Location = TextBoxLocation.Text;
    singleEvent.BeginDate = TextBoxBegin.Text;
    singleEvent.EndDate= TextBoxEnd.Text;
    singleEvent.Venue = TextBoxVenue.Text;
    client.UpdateEventAsync(singleEvent);
```

However, I would like to save all of the altered text from my generated ListBoxItems, instead of just one row at a time from my DataGrid method.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you define singleEvent class to have INotifyPropertyChanged? and use BindingMode = TwoWay for all textboxes

Comment: So, I had to duplicate my class on the client side.  Here is part of my code that ended up working: `client.UpdateEventCompleted += new EventHandler<UpdateEventCompletedEventArgs>(client_UpdateEventCompleted);

                foreach (ClientClasses.ClientSideUpcomingEvent eachUpcomingEvent in AllEventsListBox.Items)
                {
                    if (eachUpcomingEvent.IsDirty)
                    {
                        client.UpdateEventAsync(eachUpcomingEvent.ServerSideUpcomingEvent);
                        eachUpcomingEvent.MarkClean();
                    }
                }`